# How to prevent dynamically generated html button from disappearing, after its creation?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create dynamically a html button and html hidden input to submit some data.
The problem is that after their creation, they disappear from the html page.
What am I doing wrong? Here it is the script code:

```js
convert_button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  showDownloadBtn();
});

let showDownloadBtn = function() {
  let downloadBtn = document.createElement('button');
  let input = document.createElement('input');
  let form = document.getElementById('DownForm');
  let div = document.getElementById8('DownBtn');

  form.setAttribute('action', 'download');
  form.setAttribute('method', 'post');

  input.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  input.setAttribute('value', `123455`);

  downloadBtn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
  downloadBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Download'));

  div.appendChild(input);
  div.appendChild(downloadBtn);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div id="UpBtn">
    <input type="file" id="inpFile">
    <button id="btnUpload">Upload file</button>
  </div>
</form>
<form id="DownForm">
  <div id="DownBtn"></div>
</form>


<div id="id_alert" class="alertmessage"></div>
```

Comment: Ammmm have you tried to remove `input.setAttribute('type','hidden');` ?

Comment: Yes i've just tried now, and i can see the filled form for just a fraction of a second,and then it just disappears

Comment: Than, use: `'click', (evt) => {` and inside `evt.preventDefault()` What currently happens: your form is actually being submitted by the browser and the page reloads. BTW... what is `convert_button` ? A button inside a form?

Comment: ok thank you, now i see why it disappears. Where should i put the code you suggested to me? The convert_button is a button to upload a file using Ajax, but i've removed that part of the code

Comment: I cannot say by just looking at your incomplete code. Create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some mistakes you've done so

1. the `convert_button` is not defined so define it
   `const convert_button = document.getElementById("btnUpload");`
2. in the line where you selected the DownBtn you accidently put a 8 there so fix that
   `let div = document.getElementById8('DownBtn');`

now it's fine and when you click down button the form get submitted and reloads the page
which is your actual problem
so the solution is that the event listener to convert_button should prevent Default so
instead of
`convert_button.addEventListener('click', () => { showDownloadBtn(); });`
do this
`convert_button.addEventListener('click', (e) => { e.preventDefault(); showDownloadBtn(); });`

then another problem occurs that it keeps adding buttons to the site which we don't want (I Guess)
take a variable like
`let isButtonAdded = false;`
and check the variable before we call `showDownloadBtn()`
 `if(isButtonAdded === false){ showDownloadBtn(); }`
and set it to true when we add the button to page
`isButtonAdded = true; div.appendChild(input);`

so the whole code is as follow

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <div id="UpBtn">
        <input type="file" id="inpFile" />
        <button id="btnUpload">Upload file</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    <form id="DownForm">
      <div id="DownBtn"></div>
    </form>

    <div id="id_alert" class="alertmessage"></div>

    <script>
      let isButtonAdded = false;
      const convert_button = document.getElementById("btnUpload");
      convert_button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (isButtonAdded === false) {
          showDownloadBtn();
        }
      });

      let showDownloadBtn = function () {
        let downloadBtn = document.createElement("button");
        let input = document.createElement("input");
        let form = document.getElementById("DownForm");
        let div = document.getElementById("DownBtn");

        form.setAttribute("action", "download");
        form.setAttribute("method", "post");

        input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        input.setAttribute("value", `123455`);

        downloadBtn.setAttribute("type", "button");
        downloadBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Download"));

        isButtonAdded = true;
        div.appendChild(input);
        div.appendChild(downloadBtn);
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem is solved. As for the `convert_button` , i declared it in my code but i didn't copy it here in the question. The adding of the buttons was another problem that i had to address once solved the autosubmit. Thanks also for solving that one.

Comment: I just copied your code and quoted all the problems and solutions I had !